# Elasticsearch: Automatically deleting old records to avoid disk space shortage

Tags: elasticsearch, storage, fifo

## The situation

I am using an ES cluster to keep logs for a certain microservice. I am usually interested with the most recent ones, and having older records is a nice-to-have.

## The problem

Naturally, I do not want to delete old entries manually, or run into low-storage situation.

## The question

**Is there a way to automatically (or periodically) delete the oldest records when new records are inserted, to keep the disk below (say) 80% capacity?**

Comment: You should have a look at the curator tool: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html